# Why is @app.route('/<data>') ? not working?

Tags: python, curl, flask

I am trying to pass the data to a python flask server on the index/root url. Is there a way to do it or what am I doing wrong?

The following is my code:

```html
import json
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<data>', methods=['POST'])
def index(data):
 #test = request.args.get('test')
 return data
```

When I run the command, it fails

```
curl  -d "data=123" http://localhost:9000/
```

The result from the python server

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The response from the curl command

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

RESOLVED WITH

```html
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
 return request.form.get('data')
```

With request

```
curl  -d 'data=test' http://localhost:9000/
```

Output was test

Comment: can you try `curl  -d "data=123" http://localhost:9000/whatever`? it should print `whatever` to stdout...

Comment: hey man, mark somebody's answer as best or at least rate it up. People helped you with your question and there are only -1 or 0, although there are correct answers.

Comment: Okay gotcha completely forgot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route defintion expects a request to `/<somedata>`. If you omit `<somedata>`, it won't parse.

To `POST` json to `/`, do this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    return jsonify({'res':data})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You can test that by doing this:

```
$ curl -d '{"foo":"bar"}' localhost:5000/
```

To `POST` form-data to `/`, as you did in your example, do

```
data = request.form['foo']
return data
```

instead. Test with

```
$ curl -d 'foo=bar' localhost:5000/
```

To just pass a string to your route via urlquery, you can do:

```
@app.route('/<string:data>', methods=['POST'])
def index(data):
    return data
```

And test that with

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:5000/somestring
```

Comment: This worked, but what if I want to get a string instead. request.get_json becomes?

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to do:

```
@app.route('/<data>', methods=['POST'])
def index(data):
    return json.dumps(data)
```

Although I am using blueprint.route to be honest, not app.route.

Comment: do you have any other routes on '/'? Could you try to change it for instance to '/api/<data>' and test.

Comment: But why do you put data in body for POST operation? data is a part of the route. like if you do `curl  -d "data=123" http://localhost:9000/hello` you should get response 'hello' in my example. Not 123. For getting a body of POST request you need to do `request.get_json()`.

Answer (score -1):

For me,
this works fine.

```
@api.route('/api/v3/ticket/<string:key>/<int:id>'
```

its `<type:var>` combination, I believe.

```
@app.route('/<data>', methods=['POST'])
def index(data):
    #test = request.args.get('test')
    print data
```

Editing with more explanation. 
When I ran your problem. 
like this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018 22:17:29] "POST /haha HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 179-733-809
haha
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018 22:16:50] "POST /haha HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 557, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/sworks/flask_application_new/flask-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Then when you return data like this ,

```
@app.route('/<data>', methods=['POST'])
def index(data):
    #test = request.args.get('test')
    return data



* Detected change in '/home/sworks/vms_temp/vms_enhancement/vms_api/smartworks/controllers_v1.py', reloading
     * Restarting with stat
     * Debugger is active!
     * Debugger PIN: 179-733-809
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018 22:17:29] "POST /haha HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I guess, try a return at the end  and it will work for you.

Comment: that works, but the specifications for me is with the the url '/'

Comment: Updated it. If it is not what you want, maybe, I am not getting what you want to achieve.

Comment: That works, but I the specification wants the data in before the url like the one I had

Comment: Oh, I got it. Let me check n try again.

Comment: I got it I have to do 
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
 print request.form.get('data')
with 
curl  -d 'data=test' http://localhost:9000/